# CSS multiple backgrounds - one to repeat

Tags: html, css, background

CSS backgrounds, I know how to make the magic work with CSS3 however this leaves the older browsers behind. My current code is...

```
body
{
font-family             : "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial;
font-size               : 11px;
color                   : #000;
text-align              : center;
margin                  : 0;    
background              : url('images/background.jpg') top center no-repeat, url('images/grassBackground.jpg') center center repeat-y;
background-size         : 100%;
}
```

grassBackground needs to repeat and background to be 100% width and keep ratio. Not sure how to make it work without CSS3 backwards?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. You will need to create a new wrapper/container element for the 2nd background.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with:

```
html {
height                  : 100%;
background              : url('images/grassBackground.jpg') top center repeat-y;
background-size         : 100%;
}
body
{
font-family             : "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial;
font-size               : 11px;
color                   : #000;
text-align              : center;
margin                  : 0;    
background              :  url('images/background.jpg') top center no-repeat;
background-size         : 100%;
height                  : 100%;
}
```